# HackerGuardian - Comodo

Tags: security, credit-card

A customer came to me saying she received an email from Comodo Group to say their HacketrGuardian PCI Scanning account will expire in 15 days. The site was done by someone else a long time ago.

I checked the customer's site, it has one section to enter your credit card details which is protected by Instant SSL by Comodo. I logged in hackerguardian.com, it says the hackerguardian account has expired 6 months ago and there is no report/history.

I did some research but still am confused by this hackerguardian, can someone please help me to understand/learn this further.

1) What kind of website needs it?
2) how do I identify if the site was using it or not before?
3) How to renew it?
4) Do I need to implement any code to the site? Or is it an off website thing? (looks like scan off site)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all to do with PCI (*Payment Card Industry*) compliance within the e-commerce world.
A group, known as the PCI council consists of the five major credit card companies. They came up with a set of security standards in order to ensure that there is consistency throughout when processing credit cards.
In order to be PCI compliant, network security scans, or PCI scans, are mandatory for all merchants and service providers that collect, process, or transmit payment card account information.
If you are a merchant or service provider and accept credit cards you must confirm PCI compliance at least once a year.
**TLDR:** It basically there to ensure that both your business and your customers remain safe when purchasing things online by performing remote security tests on your website.

And as it's a paid service done by COMODO in the cloud (remotely), no code needs to be implemented.

Comment: Thank you very Ben, I will look into it further. Thanks.